# Angular Material Design mat-checkbox error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

[image]

I am using mat-checkbox and for some reason there's another checkbox inside it. Any ideas why that could happen?

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" [indeterminate]="!checked && selectedRows?.length > 0" (click)="selectAllRowsInPage()"></mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include css file in your index html.

`<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">` 
and stackblitz code is here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zynobt?file=src/index.html for more details visit:`https://material.angular.io/guide/theming`